# How to pass data from ViewController to UITabBarController in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have been trying to pass data from the ViewController to UITabBarController programmatically.

Here is the code initial ViewController

```
 let vc = ViewController(nibName: "ViewController", bundle: nil)

    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen //or .overFullScreen for transparency
    vc.text2 = "text 222"
    
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

UITabBarConroller Code:

```
 class ViewController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

var text2: String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    print("text2", text2 ?? "empty")

    self.delegate = self
    if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
           let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
           appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
           UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
           UITabBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance
       }
    

}
```

My problem is that I'm attempting to receive data from the initial viewController to the UITabBarController, but nothing is being received, but the tabBar controller view appears.

Any help much appreciated pls...

Comment: And what problem you are facing?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve with this code and what doesn't work?

Comment: @lazarevzubov data is not pass in from controller to UITabBarController?

Comment: @DharmeshKheni Data is not receiving in UITabBarController view

Comment: With very limited code provided, it is tough to reproduce locally. It would be helpful if you created a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @NiravD updated by question please check it

Comment: @lazarevzubov updated by question please check it

Comment: @DharmeshKheni  updated by question please check it

Comment: You are presenting tabbar then pushing it in navigation and then again presenting it, you need to do one of this only, remove the first present and pushViewController line

Comment: @NiravD Actually that is tried code. sorry for confuse. removed the line now. Data passed and but not navigated to tabbarController view

Answer (score 0):

let vc = ViewController(nibName: "ViewController", bundle: nil)

vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen //or .overFullScreen for transparency

NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NotificationConstant.text, object: nil, userInfo: ["text2": ""] )

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

///// UITabBarController

class ViewController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleText(notification:)), name: NotificationConstant.text, object: nil)
    }
  @objc func handleText(notification: NSNotification) {
        guard let text = notification.userInfo?["text"] as? String else { return }
       print(text)
    }
    

    
}
```

class NotificationConstant {

```
// MARK:- Global Notifiication Names
static let text = Notification.Name("text")
```

}